# How does the unit circle work for trigonometric ratios of obtuse angles?

Tags: trigonometry

How does the unit circle work for trigonometric ratios of obtuse angles? I know that the x coordinate is cos(θ) and the y coordinate is sin(θ). But I understand these in context of only acute angles? I don't understand why the unit circle definition works for other than acute angles? Somebody please provide me some good intuition.

Comment: You may find [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145828/409) helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the unit circle work for trigonometric ratios of non-acute angles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650091/how-does-the-unit-circle-work-for-trigonometric-ratios-of-non-acute-angles) -- in fact the wording of the question is _exactly the same._

Answer (score 1):

Take the ratios $x/r$ and $y/r$ as the *defintions* of cosine and sine. Note that the definitions you already know for acute angles (“opposite side/hypotenuse” etc) then become a special case.

Comment: I would prefer this to be reintroduced as defintions in high school for all angles when students get to coordinate geometry.